# Evaluate $\int_{0}^{\pi/4}\frac{6 - 6\sin^{2}(x)}{2\cos^2(x)} \mathrm{d}x $

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Evaluate $$\int_{0}^{\pi/4}\frac{6 - 6\sin^{2}(x)}{2\cos^2(x)} \mathrm{d}x $$

Comment: So...what have you attempted so far?

Answer (score 2):

**HINT :**

$$
\cos^2 x=1-\sin^2 x.
$$
and rewrite
$$
\int_0^\frac{\pi}{4}\frac{6-6\sin^2 x}{2\cos^2 x}dx=\int_0^\frac{\pi}{4}\frac{6(1-\sin^2 x)}{2\cos^2 x}dx
$$

$$\\$$

---

$$\Large\color{blue}{\text{# }\mathbb{Q.E.D.}\text{ #}}$$

Answer (score 2):

We are given the following integral

$$\int_0^{\pi/4} \dfrac{6 - 6\sin^2(x)}{2\cos^2(x)}\,dx$$

Write it as

$$\int_0^{\pi/4} \dfrac{6(1 - \sin^2(x))}{2\cos^2(x)}\,dx = \int_0^{\pi/4} 3\dfrac{(1 - \sin^2(x))}{\cos^2(x)}\,dx$$

Use the identity $1 - \sin^2(x) = \cos^2(x)$ and simplify the integral.